# Can I set the user's photo to Titanium ACS?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, acs

I need to add a photo to my user, by doing it from the web interface, I got the photo set to a field called `photo` , but if I try to do the same thing programmatically from the mobile app it doesn't work.

`photonativePath` is my photo url from camera or gallery.

```
Cloud.Users.update({
    email: 'joeuser@mycompany.com',
    first_name: 'joe',
    last_name: 'user',
    photo : Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(photonativePath),
    custom_fields: {
        favorite_color: 'blue',
        age: 25
    }
}, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        var user = e.users[0];
        alert('Success:\n' +
            'id: ' + user.id + '\n' +
            'first name: ' + user.first_name + '\n' +
            'last name: ' + user.last_name);
    } else {
        alert('Error:\n' +
            ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
```

Comment: What error you're getting?

Comment: Also what is the value of photonativePath

Comment: photonativePath is my photo url from camera or gallery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following,
You can open the photoGallery using the openPhotoGallery method. This will open the image from the gallery and select the picture. It will update the picture in success callback

```
function openPhotoGallery(){
    Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery({
        success: function (event){
            var image=event.media;
            var imgvwTest = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                image : image
            });
            updatePhoto(imgvwTest.toImage());
        },
        cancel:function(){
            Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
                title:'Error', 
                message:'An error occured while trying to reference your gallery!'
            }).show();
        },
        error:function(er){
            Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
                title:'Error', 
                message:'An error occured while trying to reference your gallery!'
            }).show();
        }
    });

}

function updatePhoto(selectedImage){

    Cloud.Users.update({
        email: 'joeuser@mycompany.com',
        first_name: 'joe',
        last_name: 'user',
        photo : selectedImage.media,
        custom_fields: {
            favorite_color: 'blue',
            age: 25
        }
    }, function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
            var user = e.users[0];
            alert('Success:\n' +
                'id: ' + user.id + '\n' +
                'first name: ' + user.first_name + '\n' +
                'last name: ' + user.last_name);
        } else {
            alert('Error:\n' +
                ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
}
```

Please let me know if you have any issues

Comment: doesn't work, i'v success but the photo has not been set

Comment: Have you checked the photo in ACS Server? Is it available there?

Comment: okay same code worked for me!!! Can you try using selectedImage.media instead of selectedImage in updatePhoto Method?